# Custom log collection

Tags: linux, logging, tail

I need to find some open source log management system for central log. The log format is unstructured on multiple host and I need to collect and send these log on central log system. The best way is to use some kind of "tail" these logs and send to central log system.

Do you know any solution that can tail some file and send to remote central log system?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [ELK-Stack](https://www.elastic.co/elk-stack) or [Graylog](https://www.graylog.org/) both satisfy your requirements. In both solutions you can use logstash or an other tool like [filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat) or the graylog [collector sidecar](http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.4/pages/collector_sidecar.html) for log shipping. A pricey solution would be [Splunk](https://www.splunk.com/).

I personally recommend Graylog, because it has a lot of open source features like authentication and authorization for example out of the box which ELK does not have. There you have to pay for those features.